# .htaccess Rewrite rule multiple pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Have been trying to work this out for some hours now but not getting it right.

I have a site [www.example.com/user.php?username=john](http://www.example.com/user.php?username=john)
I use `.htaccess` to make it pretty like so [www.example.com/user/john](http://www.example.com/user/john)
I use the following `.htaccess` Rewrite rule and it works

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))$ ./user.php?username=$1 [L]
```

**The problem**

I have a profile page like [www.example.com/profile.php?username=john](http://www.example.com/user.php?username=john)
I also use the following `.htaccess` to make it good looking like [www.example.com/profile/john](http://www.example.com/user/john)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))$ ./profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Now, this doesn't work at all but when I remove the first rewrite rule (rule user.php) and place it after the second rewrite rule (rule profile.php) my profile page works, and vice versa,

**So it's basically whatever rule I place first is what determines what page I can access with my URL.**

I need it to work for both pages. I will agree with you am not close to a beginner level at `.htaccess` rewrite.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following. Since URLs are having their uniqueness so its better to check condition in their `%{REQUEST_URI}` value, I am checking if REQUEST_URI starts from `user` then go for 1 rule and if its starts with `profile` then go for another so there is no confusion(where I believe you tried very well kudos for that but since there is no segregation between conditions so hence its confusing Engine IMHO).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/user/([\w-]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /user.php?username=%1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/profile/([\w-]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /profile.php?username=%1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try below as well, checking first if the incoming request is neither a file nor a directory and then check for matching pattern.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^user/([\w-]+)/?$ /user.php?username=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/([\w-]+)/?$ /profile.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```